# Rendering image in Jquery throws 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, image

I am trying to show the pictures in jquery, which comes from ajax request in rails.

Here is my Jquery code;

```
<script>

    (function ( $ ) {

      $('#map-canvas').mapSearch({
        request_uri: 'locations/show.json', 
        initialPosition: [ <%= @initlat %> , <%= @initlng %> ],
        filters_form : '#filters',
        listing_template : function(listing){ 
          var pics = listing.pic.image.thumb.url
          pics = (pics.slice(1));
          console.log(pics)
                    return '<div class="listing">'
                      +     '<h3>'+listing.loc.address + '</h3>'
                      +   '<div class="row">'
                      +        '<div class="col-sm-2">'
                      +         '<img src= "pics" >' //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
                      +          '</div>'
                      +        '<div class="col-sm-5">'
                      +           '<p><strong>Address : </strong>' + listing.address+ '</p>'
                      +               '<p>'+listing.address+', '+listing.address+' '+listing.address+'</p>'
                      +               '<p>Reg Year: ' + listing.address+'</p>'
                      +          '</div>'
                      +        '<div class="col-sm-5">'
                      +         '<p><strong>demo:</strong> '+listing.address+'</p>'
                      +         '<p><strong>demo:</strong> '+listing.address+'</p>'
                      +          '</div>'
                      +   '</div>'
                      +  '</div>';
                  },
        marker_clusterer : true
      });
    }( jQuery ));

  </script>
```

Console log works as;

```
uploads/picture/image/987/thumb_images.jpg
uploads/picture/image/988/thumb_imgres-4.jpg
uploads/picture/image/989/thumb_imgres-3.jpg
uploads/picture/image/990/thumb_imgres-4.jpg
```

At first, I thought it throws error because there is a forward slash at the beginning of the link as, `/uploads/picture/image/987/thumb_images.jpg`, but when I slice it, it still gives an error. I think there is something wrong with `+         '<img src= "pics" >'` part. Because when I put the path directly as, `+         '<img src= "uploads/picture/image/987/thumb_images.jpg" >'` it works fine. But pictures are dynamic. I think the problem happens because, `'<img src= "pics" >'` code seems as string and jquery does not put `var pics` variable there.

Thank you!

Comment: concat  variable  like this  '<img src= "'+pics+'" >'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to concat variable using `+`.   read [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp) more about `+` operator in javascript

```
  '<img src= "'+pics+'" >'
```